# android, add Marker from Bitmap on googlemap

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using googlemap-android-api v2, and want to create the marker from a Bitmap at runtime. So I do:

```
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        //create the thumbnail to use as marker
        Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap,10,10);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(currentLatLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(thumbnail));
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
```

It never seems to work, I'm sure both `bitmap` and `thumbnail` are not null. If instead of `.fromBitmap`, I use `.fromResource(R.drawable.some_image)` then it shows. However, as I said, I want to change at run-time from user's input.

Any tip? thanks

**Updated:**
The marker does show if I add it (i.e, use the above code) at `onResume()` of the Activity/Fragment that host the map. Before I use this code at `onActivityResult()`, after the user browse a file to get the `filePath`. To me, it's still strange since `onActivityResult()` is on the UI thread. Anyway, whatever works.

Comment: Hi , have you tried changing values in extractThumbnail ? 10, 10 it's very small.

Answer (score 9):

I am doing the same this like following

First I create a Drawable from a path on runtime

```
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(filePath);
```

Then I simply add it to marker like this

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(location)
            .title(title)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap())));
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: tks for sharing. It still doesn't show. LogCat shows `ERROR/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5951): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.` My map and other marker (created using `fromResource`) shows, so I don't know what that error means.

Comment: What's the file path? Is it to a local file or file on the server?

Comment: tks for follow-up, it's a local file. Actually I figured it out and updated my post.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a marker object then you can use it like the below method.

```
 Bitmap smallDot = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(getApplicationContext(),
                R.drawable.red_dot), 15, 15, false);

marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallDot));
```